# Why is `tr` replacing one character with two?

Tags: linux, shell, tr

I am using `tr` (GNU coreutils v8.32) to transliterate non-basic-Latin characters into basic Latin, and it is replacing them with characters I didn't tell it to or more than one of the desired character.

Example:

```
% echo é | tr é e
> ee
```

What's going on?

Comment: Try `echo é | xxd`

Comment: My previous comment is alluding to the fact that your accented `e` is actually 2 bytes. `tr` is byte-oriented so it doesn't work. `sed` will work though `echo é | sed 's/é/elephant/'` So your `tr` command might become `echo éà | sed -e 's/é/elephant/g' -e 's/à/antelope/g'`

Comment: Thanks, Mark. I ended up converting all the `tr` commands to `sed` for the reason you described. If you want to put your comment in an answer, I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is that `tr` is oriented to the transliteration of *single* bytes, but if you look at your `é`, you will see it is two bytes, plus a linefeed:

```
echo é | xxd                                         
00000000: c3a9 0a                                  ...
```

I think you need to look to `sed` which is oriented towards patterns, however long they may be:

```
echo éàéà | sed -e 's/é/elephant/g' -e 's/à/antelope/g'
elephantantelopeelephantantelope
```

Answer (score 2):

`é` has two bytes, maybe that's why `tr` produces two `e`.

You can achieve the epxected effect with :

```
echo 'é' | iconv -t ASCII//TRANSLIT
```

Comment: Yes, [GNU tr doesn't really work for multibyte chars such as UTF-8](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Character-arrays.html) which nearly all Linuxes today use at least by default

Comment: Philippe, I hadn't heard of `iconv`, but it appears I was recreating its functionality with my `tr` script, so thank you for bringing it to my attention.